# Can an N registered aircraft operate scheduled service from USA to/from a Category 2 country?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, commercial-operations

Am looking at economics of a scheduled service between Honolulu and Tarawa but need an N registered aircraft to do it.

Comment: Can you fill us in more on what a "Category 2" country is?

Comment: This one is probably more of a question pertaining to policies of the US Dept of State than Aviation.

Comment: Possibly [IASA categories](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/iasa/media/FAA_Initiatives_IASA.pdf) (compliance with ICAO safety standards). Need to be clarified. A [Category 2 country](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/iasa/definitions/) is one where an operator of this country cannot open a new service/codeshare with the USA. [Example](https://travelcodex.com/india-downgraded-to-category-2-safety-rating-by-us-faa/) and [return](https://travelcodex.com/the-challenges-of-the-us-india-nonstop-market-its-time-for-facts-and-figures/).

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about this question. It's very specific. Vote to reopen

Comment: @TomMcW: This is about which category the OP is talking about. The OP can clarify easily.